# R ggplot annotation alignment

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, annotations, geom-text

I am trying to create an annotation and align it. If I use:

```
annotate("text", label = "atext", x = 1, y = 1)
```

the center of the text (the `e`) gets positioned at `(1, 1)`. However, I'd like the left border of the text (the `a`) to be at `(1, 1)`. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 8):

use `hjust` for  horizontal justification.

```
annotate("text", label = "atext", x = 1, y = 1, hjust = 0)
```

Look at [**`vjust`** *and* **`hjust`**](https://www.r-bloggers.com/hjust-and-vjust/) for more information;

This is a graph that shows how different values of above parameters control justification (and angle).

[image: hjust, vjust and angle]